# Magento 2.4: bin/magento commands not working after installing cpanel on my VPS

Tags: magento2

I tried installing cpanel on my VPS (which already had a Magento 2.4.4 instance working on it) using this guide: https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-cpanel-whm-on-ubuntu-20-04/

The cpanel did not work, however, I also noticed that I couldnt access the Magento website.
It is giving me this error:
[image]

And when I run php bin/magento setup:upgrade I get this error:
[image]

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Have you configured the database correctly in app/etc/env.php file? That is hostname, port, database name, username, etc... if yes then please cross check if database exist

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you.

1. Check the apache or ngnix installed.
2. Check MySQL and PHP installed and check PHP modules.
3. Check the vhost settings.